# IF formula returning a value error or incorrect calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to get the following conditions in the same formula:

1. `=IF(AND(Input!F51="",Input!G51=""),0)`
2. `IF(Input!F51="",Lookups!AM3*Input!G51*Lookups!AF6)`
3. `IF(Input!G51="",B23*Input!F51*Lookups!AF6)`

I've tried formatting this several ways but either get a #VALUE! error, or the cell returns 0.00 rather than the correct calculation. Please can someone let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nest:

```
=IF(AND(Input!F51="",Input!G51=""),0,IF(Input!F51="",Lookups!AM3*Input!G51*Lookups!AF6,B23*Input!F51*Lookups!AF6))
```